# svn mergeinfo - E195016: "must be ancestrally related"

Tags: svn, svn-merge, svn-mergeinfo

Although there are several similar questions here (e.g., [SVN - Reintegration Merge error: "must be ancestrally related"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/490164/svn-reintegration-merge-error-must-be-ancestrally-related)) and on the Web, I wasn't able to figure out why `svn mergeinfo <file>` causes an error in all of my SVN repositories. In contrast to all other Q&As that I have found, I am actually able to execute `svn merge` successfully. For example, undoing a previous commit to a `pom.xml`file:

```
svn merge -r 17409:17408 pom.xml
--- Reverse-merging r17409 into 'pom.xml':
U    pom.xml
--- Recording mergeinfo for reverse merge of r17409 into 'pom.xml':
U   pom.xml
--- Eliding mergeinfo from 'pom.xml':
U   pom.xml
```

However, when I execute `svn mergeinfo`, I get the following error:

```
svn: E195016: 'https://../trunk/MyProject/pom.xml@50446' must be ancestrally related to
'https://../trunk/MyProject@50446'
```

In this example, 50446 is the current head revision number and I get that same error for every file I've tried. Only when I execute the mergeinfo command on the top directory itself, it works:

```
svn mergeinfo .
    youngest common ancestor
    |         last full merge
    |         |        tip of branch
    |         |        |         repository path
    50446              50446   
    |                  |       
  -------| |------------         ../trunk/MyProject
     \                         
      \                        
       --| |------------         ../trunk/MyProject
                       |       
                       50446
```

And even stranger, I don't find any mergeinfo properties set. Commands like `svn propget svn:mergeinfo --recursive` or `svn propget svn:mergeinfo --depth=infinity` don't output anything and return successfully with status code 0.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix our files to be "ancestrally related" again to the projects they are located in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: `svn mergeinfo <file>` is wrong.

From the SVN documentation (svn help mergeinfo):

> "Summarize the history of merging between SOURCE and TARGET."
>
> "SOURCE and TARGET are the source and target branch URLs, respectively."
>
> "The default TARGET is the current working directory ('.')."

So, if your command was something like `svn mergeinfo pom.xml`, then the error message is as expected, since there's no "ancestrally relation" between that file and it's directory.
The correct command would be: `svn mergeinfo pom.xml pom.xml`, that will compare those two files, and probably is what you want.

When you run `svn mergeinfo .`, it's the same as running `svn mergeinfo . .`. So it works and you get the mergeinfo output.

You could also run `svn mergeinfo pom.xml pom.xml@12345`, to compare a specific revision.

---

You can also get this error when trying to merge things that are not related.
If you created the directory tree or files manually (I mean: without using the branch feature), then they are not related and you will get this error.

Please read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22204268/tortoise-svn-merge-must-be-ancestrally-related-to-error) and note that the author created the branch `dev` manually, breaking SVN.

The best solution in this case would be to create the branch normally, migrate all files to this branch manually (copy-paste everything) and then merge it back to trunk.

Comment: Far back in the history I see a commit (with `svn log --verbose --stop-on-copy`) where someone moved a directory by deleting it `D /base/trunk/lib/plugin` and adding it into another trunk `A /tools/trunk/plugin (from /base/trunk/lib/plugin:16026)`. Would that be an explanation of why I get those errors?

Comment: @dokaspar I reread your question and noticed I have misunderstood your problem. Improved my answer to correctly address your issue. Please, could you check it?

Comment: so again it all boils down to RTFM :)

Comment: @dokaspar I would not say it like that, but yes: the information was in the manual. And I also misinterpreted your question, and gave you a wrong answer in my first attempt. But glad it helped you solve your issue.